# Better documentation for arcgisimage, basemap python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am using the arcgisimage API to have map layers to my scatterplot.

However, the documentation for the API, found here http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backgrounds.html is not that good, especially concerning sizing of the images:

> xpixels actually sets the zoom of the image. A bigger number will ask
>   a bigger image, so the image will have more detail. So when the zoom
>   is bigger, the xsize must be bigger to maintain the resolution
>
> dpi is the image resolution at the output device. Changing its value
>   will change the number of pixels, but not the zoom level

THe xsize mentioned is not defined anywhere, and doubling the DPI between 300 and 600 doesn't affect the size of the image.

Anyone have a better documentation/tutorial?

Comment: There are official docs http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/index.html and examples http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html, but for this particular feature I can't see much, or an example. I'd suggest playing with various values to see the effect, and/or dive into the matplotlib source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am learning about some similar things...And I am new to it. So what I can do is to offer some simple ideas in my mind. Wish this will help you.(Although it seems not likely to do so. ^_^ ) 
The following code is from the given example of tutorial by adding some adjustments. (LA centered)

```
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-118.5,llcrnrlat=33.15,urcrnrlon=-117.15,urcrnrlat=34.5, epsg=4269)
    #http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services
    #EPSG Number of America is 4269

    map.arcgisimage(service='World_Physical_Map', xpixels = 1500, verbose= True)
    plt.show()
```

Firstly, I guess here "xsize" equals "xpixels", or just should be "size" (a misspelling? I'm not sure of that). As told in the tutorial, what "xpixel" influence is the resolution of the final figure and the size of it.

When **xpixels=150**, you'll get the following picture (about 206KB):
[image: 206KB]
However when **xpixels=1500**, you'll get a picture with higher resolution (about 278KB). Also when you zoom in to figure out the detail, this picture is clearer than the former one. 
[image: 273KB]

If you want to see the picture with bigger zoom, you need to set "xpixels" to a larger value to keep it clear.(That is to maintain the resolution. I guess they gave out just a few simple explaination without many details.) And I have no idea what "dpi" is used for...It is like first time you cut a cake into 300 grids, then the second time you cut it into 600 grids. The figure won't be clearer. And from your saying I know that neither will it become a bigger graph.